# How to use find and replace to replace a character with new line

Tags: macos, text, textedit

I have a document, I wants to use the find and replace to convert any period (`.`) into a new line. I can't seems to of that, in Microsoft word you can input <kbd>^ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> into the replace field. But how do you do it on apps like Pages or TextEdit?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can click on the magnifying glass icon and choose **Insert Pattern** or press <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ ALT</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

[image: Insert pattern in TextEdit screenshot]

Then pick **Line Break**

[image: Line Break selected]

Answer (score 11):

A simple trick is to just copy the rest of a line and paste it into the "replace" field.

Works with Textedit, Xcode etc.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Find and Replace in Mac Pages version 8.0 doesn't have the 'Insert Pattern' as TextEdit does. Pages' Help does not provide information about how to use Paragraph Break, Line Break etc. But the following can be used:

```
\n for paragraph break
\i for line break
\t for tab
```

(found these out using 'Edit - Selection to Find')