Find & Replace with Carriage Return in iOS Notes
In Notes, how can I use Find&Replaxe and insert a carriage return (or a new line or a line break) as the REPLACE WITH entry?
PS: at the moment, I use a custom keyboard substitution, but this is cumbersome.

I don't think stock find & replace can do this. Even when you copy two characters with a newline in between and paste that into the replace field, the newline gets turned into a space. Someone would've had to explicitly design it this way.

Answer for macOS: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227052/how-to-use-find-and-replace-to-replace-a-character-with-new-line
